# Chess Golf: Peaceful Double Mate

Tags: chess

Given the board below, create a checkmate for both sides, ensuring that no pieces are capable of capturing any other piece excluding captures targeted at the kings.

[image: Board]

Blue moves south and pink moves north.

Turns between colors are not needed here, move the pieces in any order so long as they move within the rules respective to the piece being moved.

The winning board will have the fewest moves possible while ensuring that:

- Blue is in checkmate.
- Pink is in checkmate.
- Every piece but the kings are not at risk of being captured by another piece.

Remember that friendly fire is enabled so each side can also capture their own pieces too.

This is chess golf so the fewest number of moves wins. Also, being the first in the series this one is simple to ensure everyone has a chance to solve it. I will mark the winner correct on Friday to give new comers time to solve.

Comment: Which colour is going which way?

Comment: @boboquack I've updated the post to add clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a [chess-golf] tag already after one puzzle. For the moment, [chess] works fine, it's only after a genre becomes popular we create a tag here, and not even then; even the [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=riley) don't have their own tag.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The image was the ordinary A8 on top left and H1 on bottom right; is that right? Also "Turns between colors are not needed here, move the pieces in any order so long as they move within the rules respective to the piece being moved." we still need to use white-black-white or black-white-black move order respectively?

Comment: I'm amazed that this puzzle only got a +1 balance of votes. At the very least, it deserves credit for pointing out how difficult it has been for all of those who tried it to get used to many unusual rules and unusual display. But more than that, in the end when you understand what has to be done it is very far from being as trivial as all current answers seem to imply.

Comment: @PerpetualJ You said in a comment that a king's escape route could be considered blocked by friendly fire. Is it true that the very piece delivering check in a checkmate could be friendly fire as well?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That is correct

Comment: @PerpetualJ Thanks! And is it still considered checkmate if a pink piece could come rescue the blue king from pink's own attack (for instance by coming in the way of the attacking piece)?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier no, traditional checkmate rules still apply. Pieces must not be able to prevent the mate.

Comment: That is not really traditional: traditionally, only the pieces of the defender can prevent check from being mate, not the pieces of the attacker.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier so, traditional in the sense that even with friendly fire the mate cannot be prevented lol I should really learn to be more specific sometimes.

Comment: For instance, imagine that we remove the queen from the board. Then the pink bishop can block the pink rook's attack by coming to a6, therefore the blue king is not in checkmate, right?

Comment: I'm not sure [tag:chess-golf] is compatible with the community's fairly recent decision to declare [the end of open-ended puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617). Taken literally, the objective to "solve within as few moves as possible"—interpreted as requiring a solution in a ***provably*** minimal number of moves, where part of an answer is demonstrating such proof—would be fine, but "golf" rules (notably as seen on Code Golf) generally aren't done that way. As it seems this is intended to be the first of a series, I need to say I strongly believe this format is off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do it in

> 5 moves.

Observe that

> both kings would be in checkmate were it not for the queen which can come to a5 to block the rook's attack and the pink bishop which can come to f1 or a6, blocking the attack on either of the kings.
>
>
>  Also, there is a triple attack on the blue bishop and an attack on the pink knight.

The moves

> Nf6, Bd6, Ra5, Bb1, Qxb1 take care of all these problems and result in a situation as demanded.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the blue king is still checkmatesd after that, or if it can escape under friendly fire on b8.

Comment: My interpretation is the former, but that would need to be made clear by the OP.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Your interpretation is correct. The king is still in checkmate due to friendly fire.

Comment: If you do the 2 moves suggested, the first piece threatens the other.

Comment: You’re welcome. Another issue: Bf1 blocks check.

Answer (score 3):

3 moves.

> Bh7 Move the pink Bishop away from threatening to block the Queen.
>  Bf4 Move the blue Bishop away from capture.
>  Kf6 Move the knight away from capture.

This leaves both kings in checkmate and no piece threatened. The blue bishop constrains both kings.

Comment: Friendly fire is enabled here. Blocking your own rook would be a threatened capture.

Comment: @PerpetualJ I missed that. Corrected now.

Comment: It's funny, you see my mistakes but not yours :) these two moves do not fix the knight being threatened by a pawn.

Comment: You’re forgetting about the pawn and knight situation

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Haha, that’s why bystanders aren’t allowed to speak when others are playing chess.

Comment: @Lawrence The queen can block the rook's attack. Hence my comments on the OP.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No, it can’t - it would then threaten its own king under friendly-fire rules.

Comment: But is that really forbidden? Well, not only that, but another couple of unusual rules were not made clear from the beginning, and one question of mine is still hanging in the OP's comments. I feel that there is room for a great puzzle here, but too many things are unclear.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Sorry, what I meant was that the queen is unable to block the rook under the friendly-fire rules, not that it was forbidden to do so.

Comment: The movement `Nf6` puts the `bishop` on `H7` in danger.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in

> Two consecutive blue moves, namely h2 and Qg1#.....but I may have massively missed the point of this puzzle....?

Comment: The blue bishop can take one of the pink pawns, so this doesn't work with the updated rules.